# Centralized PowerPoint Template

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

in our company we have a template for creating PowerPoint-presentations. Is there a way to have a centralized (e.g. in a shared folder) template, that makes all presentations based on this template change, when the template gets changed?

Maybe as a subquestion: Is there a way to "extract" the template that a presentation is based on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every presentation contains the template it was based on.  To extract it, simply save it as a template file (POT in 2003 and prior, POTX in 2007 onward).

You can opt to leave slides in the template or not, depending on how it'll be used and what you're after.

As Frank's mentioned, and in fact BECAUSE the template is included in each PPT file, there's no connection whatever back to the original template so other than having a custom add-in installed on each user's PC, there'd be no way of forcing updates from centrally located templates.

Answer (score 0):

Mhmm I don't think that's possible without some custom app to change all of the presentations separately. It's very prone to error due to the way presentations are shared(copied, passed around, moved, etc.) so there's no way to really be sure that a presentation is where you said it was.

For your sub-question; This link could be useful: http://presentationsoft.about.com/od/powerpointtips/ss/copy_colors_3.htm but other than that I doubt it.